# Git - switch between different branches on remote server

Tags: git, branch, pull

I am new to git so apologies if I have misunderstood how this should work but I have a site with the following branches:

```
master
bug/ticket-783
```

Ordinarily I would merge any branches into my `master` branch, then log into remote server through SSH and run

```
git pull origin master
```

Which works fine and updates my site as per the master branch.

Now on a development version of the site, I am hoping to apply just the `bug/ticket-783` branch. So I ran

```
git pull origin bug/ticket-783
```

Which worked, with the changes committed on that branch applied to the site.
But now after testing and checking the site I want to switch the site back to the master branch. I had (wrongly expected that I could run

```
git pull origin master
```

Again and it would no longer have any code changes that were specific to `bug/ticket-783`.
However it jst says it is already up to date. And the site is stuck on the changes made in the `bug/ticket-783`. Full output is:

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
88u7a7e..ab6tb93  master     -> origin/master
Already up to date.
```

How can i get the remote server back to the master branch state?
Is there a way I can switch between pulling the master branch and other branches?

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` does not navigate you between branches, it fetches changes from the specified branch and **merges** them into the current branch. If you need to switch between branches use [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) or (if you have git version 2.27 or later installed) [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch):

```
git checkout master
```

Also be advised that if you try to checkout a remote branch, you will end up with `detached HEAD` state. So you always want to checkout local branches (until you going to just check some state of the code in remote, but there are simpler ways to do that) and make them track changes from remote server.

Answer (score -1):

This should work 
"Git checkout master"